# References for Nvidia's DLSS

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, deep-neural-networks

[Nvidia's deep learning super-sampling](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/technologies/dlss/) is presented as an application of deep learning techniques to video-rendering in videogames.

**Question:** I'm asking for a technical reference that explains what is the deep learning architecture that is behind the inner works of the Nvidia's DLSS.

Thanks in advance!